# Matlab R2014a - stepwiselm problems

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I am currently working on a timeseries model using the function `stepwiselm` in Matlab. I am running Matlab R2014a. The documentation on the function can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/stepwiselm.html).

**Introduction to the mathematical model:**

It is a standard linear model with 5 variables and about 22,000 samples of data. Thus, I have following systemet:

y = Ax, where: y~ dim[22,000 x 1] A~dim[22,000 x 5], x~dim[5 x 1]

The model should be very straightforwad with the following call:

```
mdl = stepwiselm(A,y)
```

Now this should be a very straightforward function: f = 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
Unfortunately this is not the case for Matlab.

**Problem:**

Matlab denotes the function to be of following kind:

```
y ~ 1 + x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x1*x4 + x1*x5 + x2*x3 + x2*x5 + x3*x5 + x4*x5
```

Matlab returns following:

```
1. Adding x4, FStat = 3622.5909, pValue = 0
2. Adding x5, FStat = 415.9279, pValue = 1.677113e-91
3. Adding x2, FStat = 52.1139, pValue = 5.42893e-13
4. Adding x3, FStat = 60.8965, pValue = 6.31635e-15
5. Adding x3:x5, FStat = 126.9652, pValue = 2.328284e-29
6. Adding x4:x5, FStat = 161.0195, pValue = 9.456442e-37
7. Adding x2:x3, FStat = 26.6471, pValue = 2.46608e-07
8. Adding x1, FStat = 28.4298, pValue = 9.82349e-08
9. Adding x1:x5, FStat = 160.2774, pValue = 1.369563e-36
10. Adding x1:x3, FStat = 87.8781, pValue = 7.69837e-21
11. Adding x2:x5, FStat = 26.6218, pValue = 2.4985e-07
12. Adding x1:x2, FStat = 14.5758, pValue = 0.000135047
13. Adding x1:x4, FStat = 10.4336, pValue = 0.00123946
```

Now this is very unintuitative for me that matlab chose this interaction model per default. So I have tried following to overcome this problem:

**My current solutions:**

1)
The function `stepwiselm` receives a modelspec input as described in the documentation. I have tried to include 'linear' in my call such that the call becomes:

```
mdl = stepwiselm(A,y,'linear')
```

Nevertheless this **does not** solve the problem and the output is exactly the same as before.

2) 
I also tried using the function `stepwisefit`. `stepwisefit` **DOES** actually work and make a linear prediction model. So my question is as follows:

**Question:**

I acknowledge that `stepwisefit` may be a solution to my mathematical problem but I am kean to understand why `stepwiselm` does not return a standard linear model.

Do you guys have any idea why `stepwiselm` does not return a valid linear model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stepwiselm is the newer function which means a higher likelihood of bugs but also of using a different and improved technique. I didn't see anything in the documentation to note a different algorithm. Neither did this [comment on the Mathworks site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86819-difference-between-stepwisefit-and-stepwiselm):

I believe the reason that

```
mdl = stepwiselm(A,y,'linear')
```

does not fix the problem is that it only forces the starting model to be linear, not the ending model. I believe you actually want the [upper option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/stepwiselm.html#inputarg_Upper) which seems to be more what you have in mind:

> 'Upper' — Model specification describing largest set of terms in
>   fit'interaction' (default) | string
>
> Model specification describing the largest set of terms in the fit,
>   specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'Upper' and one of
>   the string options for modelspec naming the model.
>
> Example: 'Upper','quadratic'

Is it possible that your intuition of the data generating process is wrong? One way to sort this out is residual and goodness of fit analysis. When you estimate the model with both stepwiselm and stepwisefit (or both using elm but one with a linear upper and the other without), how do the residuals of the two models compare? Are they heteroskedastic? Is the adjusted R^2 comparable in both regressions? You may be surprised to uncover relationships in the data you didn't know existed.

Comment: Bkay, thanks for your answer I appreciate it very much! Your approach to the problem was correct thus I got it working. My question to you now is whether the algorithm actually chooses the model which performs best (thus my model becomming an interaction model)?
Once again thanks.